# How can I get userId after call create user api in keycloak?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, rest, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I implemented keycloak in my node.js project and call following API for add user in keycloak:

[{{keycloak_url}}/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users](https://www.postman.com/zartu/workspace/e-t-s-public-workspace/request/7294517-f3dd8450-3605-4ce8-8ba6-1e2c15161d0e)

This API works and I can add user in keycloak but I need userId in response to this API how can I get this, any alternative way for this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

You use the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html) endpoint `GET /{realm}/users` with the query parameter `username`. For instance:

```
GET "{{keycloak_url}}/auth/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users/?username={{username}}"
```

**NOTE:** In some Keycloak version it will return all the users with a username that matches {{username*}}. Therefore, additional filtering of the list might be necessary. For those using bash script I have uploaded [to my repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Users/getPerfectMatchUserByName.sh) one example on how to do filter currently. From the response you just need to extract the field `id`.

---

The approach pointed out first by [@Sillas Reis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17542139/sillas-reis) allows to create the user and get its ID in a single call, which is more performant. However, I am not a fan of relying on non documented behavior. Nonetheless, for those using bash and curl that solution could look like the following:

Call the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html) with an *access token* from a user with the proper permissions. For now, I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm:

```bash
curl “https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token” \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=${ADMIN_NAME}” \
    -d "password=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To create the user in your realm `$REALM_NAME` and get back its `id` execute:

```bash
URL="https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users/"
curl --include -X -s POST "${URL}" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        -d "$USER_JSON" | grep "Location: ${URL}" | grep -o '[^/]\+$'
```

the flag `--include` will make `curl` include the headers, and the command `grep "Location: ${URL}"` will extract the location and the command  `grep -o '[^/]\+$'` the user ID from that location.

Answer (score 18):

I believe there is another way to do this which will save you an extra request. If you take a look at the ***reponse headers*** when you create a user, you should find a field named ***"Location"***. It looks like this:

```
Location: http://keycloak_address/auth/admin/realms/realm/users/3a11cc77-9871-4f6e-805b-bf17ea79fa3a
```

In this case the value "3a11cc77-9871-4f6e-805b-bf17ea79fa3a" would be the new user's id.